# Load a docx file(containg text and image) into RichTextBox c#

Tags: c#

Load a docx file(containg text and image) into RichTextBox c#

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these two CodeProject articles, if you combine those two they would probably be enough to get you started at least.

[Manipulate Docx with C# without Microsoft Word installed with Open XML SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ManipulateDocxWithoutMSO.aspx?msg=3505375)

[Insert Plain Text and Images into RichTextBox at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/csexrichtextbox.aspx)

Comment: To add to this answer, you may want to look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/4a1f5550-495d-4b95-81d8-25374f38dd00 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970917.aspx as well.