# Manipulating and printing docx documents in C#

Tags: c#, docx

I have developed an application in C#. I want to enable sers define their own print template for printing certificates. Currently it accepts html and replaces keywords with values. However users are not familiar with html design, converters do not give well designed result, and hand writing html code for getting the same design is time consuming.

I want to enable my application to open the docx file, replace keywords with values and print.

Any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out [Automated Search and Replace in Word 2007 documents with C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/05/13/automated-search-and-replace-in-multiple-word-2007-documents-with-c.aspx)

Also you can look at [Microsoft Word Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140287%28v=office.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: How can I display the document in an editable box after replacements done?

Comment: I don't think it will be that easy, since docx is not a plain text file, nor rich text.  It is zipped file.  Please take a look at similar question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447044/load-a-docx-filecontaing-text-and-image-into-richtextbox-c-sharp with more information

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has info about the Word Object Model.

Comment: I think it should be possible to get MS Word editor bound into my winform such that has no toolbx, no title bar and is not movable. But I am wondering how I can show up the window after document is opened and processed using object library.