# Word document. Replacement markers

Tags: c#, parsing, docx

There is a file format .docx. In this file there are markers, for example:

```
...

[FirstName][MiddleName][LastName]

...

[Date]
```

Need to replace markers with values. Values come into the function from the js.

I use c#.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the file extension from `.docx` to something like a `.lastName`?

Comment: of course not. I want to replace **markers** in docx file with values. FirstName -> John, LastName -> Doe etc.

Comment: So send the values stored in your variable `LastName` to the `.docx` file?  Sorry, but your question is a little vague...

Comment: Can I see the code so I can get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish, and how...

Comment: I have c# method with one parameter - JObject json.There are values in this json - lastName, firstName, MiddleName, Date etc. I have .docx document with marks [lastName], [middleName] etc. So this method should replace the markers in the document with values. I have not code. Don't know how can I do it.

Comment: By "markers" are you referring to Word "bookmarks" or "form fields"?  You can use Aspose for this.

Comment: By "markers" I referring places in document (predetermined) this does not apply to Word. It s just text in square brackets, nothing more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulating and printing docx documents in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140754/manipulating-and-printing-docx-documents-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on what you've told me, I'm assuming that you have something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class json
{
    string FirstName = "";
    string MiddleName = "";
    string LastName = "";
    string FullName = FirstName + " " + MiddleName + " " + LastName;

    FileStream fStream = new FileStream("fileName.docx", FileMode.Open, 
                                         FileAccess.Write, FileAshar.Write);

    public json()
    {}

    public void SendNameToFile(string fName)
    {
         fStream.Write(fName + "\n");
    }
}
```

Again, your question is kind of vague.  I'm not sure what you mean by **Markers**, but if you mean that you have fields in your `.docx` displaying `[FirstName]`, `[MiddleName`, & `[LastName]`, and you want to sub those out with your string variable values, then you have to search through your `.docx` and look for that particular `char[]` of your **Markers** and then re-assign those with your variables.

You can check out this link on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx

**"How to: Programmatically Search for and Replace Text in Documents"**

Comment: the solution here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx